# how to check for an exact string match in parameters that being passed for API call Python

Tags: python, string, api, soap, match

I am passing the parameters with a Soap Call to AdPoint platform. My parameters look like this:

```
[{'nUID': '39', 'Query': [{'MaxRecords': '40', 'OrderName': 'Forecast Placeholder - 100', 'CustomerID': '15283'}]}]
```

Passing the parameters below:

```
response = client.service.GetOrders(**params[0])
```

Because CustomerID is not unique, and 'Forecast Placeholder - 100' is a string. The response I get back might be Forecast Placeholder - 1005 or 1007 etc. I wonder if there is a way in Python to tell the code to only return the exact match. AdPoints API sucks so there is nothing that can help from API side, but Python is very powerful, so I am hoping there is a way...

Answer (score 0):

If someone could make this a comment, that would be very helpful. I don't have enough reputation to do so.

@Chique_Code, when you say:

> The response I get back might be Forecast Placeholder - 1005 or 1007 etc. I wonder if there is a way in Python to tell the code to only return the exact match

Do you mean getting `1005` or `1007` as a number from the string `Forecast Placeholder - 1005`? If so, you could use the `[:]` notation.

```py
>>> int("Forecast Placeholder - 1005"[23:]) # Returns an integer from the 23rd character to the end of the string
1005
```

Bear in mind, if you take this route `[23:]` will return a string that contains the 23rd character to the end. So if you get `"Placeholder - 1234"` and do `[23:]` you will get an empty string, as the 23rd character does not exist, so it returns an empty string.

And BTW, if you hate the API you are using, why are you using it then?

Comment: I use this SOAP API as I have no choice. All the data exist on their platform. And I am in no place to change the vendor. And what I meant is I need the response to get back the exact match of Order Name AND CustomerID. But because CustomerID is not unique and OrderName is a string I get the result with the same Customer ID but OrderName is not 100 but rather 100, 1006, 1007 and whatever else.

Comment: So do you need to change what you are sending to the API so Order Name and CustomerID match?